# How to get a integer instead of float in parsed json

Tags: scala

New to scala. Here is my code:

```
  response = HttpResponse(endpoint)
  println ("response::" + response)
  val parsedJsonscala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(response.httpResponse.body) 
   println ("parsed::" +  parsedJson)

  val result = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(response.httpResponse.body).map {
    case json: Map[String, Any] =>
      json("Id")
  }.get
```

When I print it, I get:

```
(response::,{"Id":3416824,"pId":21734944})
parsed::Some(Map(Id -> 3416824.0, pId -> 2.1734944E7))
```

How do I get the reponses for `Id` and `pID` exactly as what it is the response. Is the only option to convert back to integer after extracting it? That does not sound right as I have to check if the response has only integer values. How do I extract as is in scala.

Comment: Using a real **JSON** library instead of the old and deprecated `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON` - Also, that was removed from the stdlib a long time ago, you must be using some really old **Scala** version, I would recommend you to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest use [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core)

```
case class MyObject (Id: Int, pId: Int)
val mapper = = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)  
val data = mapper.readValue(response.httpResponse.body, classOf[MyObject])
```